# template default syntax not recognised

Tags: django

When I enter a default value for a variable in a django template using PyCharm IDE like so:

`{{ value|default_if_none:"nothing" }}`

I get a syntax error highlight in the IDE. However according to the django documentation it is the correct syntax:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default

Solutions, fixes, general hints and answers to these questions would help me:

- Did I configure something wrong? How to fix it?
- Is it a PyCharm bug? Can others confirm it? Is it known?

Comment: You should show the error you get, its nothing to do with pycharm

Comment: It does have to do with PyCharm.
To clarify: I do not get a runtime error. I get as syntax error highlight in my IDE. Everything works on the python/django side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but i had this problem myself and never found the solution till now.

In your project settings the template language is jinja2, change that to Django and it should be fixed.

[image]